# Boundary Integral Equation Method with Laplace Equation (Given NURBS curve)

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I am trying to use a boundary integral equation method to solve for laplace equation given the control points of a NURBS curve. But my BIEM is giving me very large error for numerical functions.

I first did an analytical example of a circle and it work perfectly with negligible error, but then when I moved on to do the Numerical part the solver gives very large error. I am working on with boundary function (x^2 - y^2)/(2 * pi) for both cases, and I have all my code listed below.

Can anyone help me identify the error？Thanks.
This is the analytical part:

```
N = 200
a = 1
b = 1
nxgrid = 100
nygrid = 100
xmin = -2.2
xmax = 2.2
ymin = -2.2
ymax = 2.2

theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, N + 1)
theta = theta[:-1]

x = a * np.cos(theta)
y = b * np.sin(theta)

tx = -a * np.sin(theta)
ty = b * np.cos(theta)

ax = -a * np.cos(theta)
ay = -b * np.sin(theta)
nx = np.zeros(N)
ny = np.zeros(N)
w = np.zeros(N)

for i in range(N):
    nx[i] = ax[i] / np.sqrt(ax[i] ** 2 + ay[i] ** 2)
    ny[i] = ay[i] / np.sqrt(ax[i] ** 2 + ay[i] ** 2)
    h = 1 / (N) * 2 * np.pi
    w[i] = h * np.sqrt(tx[i] ** 2 + ty[i] ** 2)

f = (x**2 - y**2) / (2*np.pi)

K = np.zeros((N, N))

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        if i == j:
            kappa = (tx[j] * ax[j] - ty[j] * ay[j]) / (tx[j] ** 2 + ty[j] ** 2) ** 1.5
            kappa = 1
            K[i, j] = -kappa / (4 * np.pi) * w[j]
        else:
            dx = x[j] - x[i]
            dy = y[j] - y[i]
            dot = nx[j] * dx + ny[j] * dy
            r = np.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2)
            K[i, j] = dot / (2 * np.pi * r ** 2)
            K[i, j] = K[i, j] * w[j]

sigma = np.linalg.solve(-np.eye(N) / 2 + K, f)

xlin = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nxgrid)
ylin = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, nygrid)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xlin, ylin)

u = np.zeros((nxgrid, nygrid))
for i in range(nxgrid):
    for j in range(nygrid):
        if (X[i, j] / a) ** 2 + (Y[i, j] / b) ** 2 >= 1:
            u[i, j] = np.nan
        else:
            u[i, j] = 0
        for k in range(N):
            dx = X[i, j] - x[k]
            dy = Y[i, j] - y[k]
            dot = nx[k] * dx + ny[k] * dy
            r = np.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2)
            u[i, j] = u[i, j] - dot / (2 * np.pi * r ** 2) * w[k] * sigma[k]     

plt.imshow(u)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

This is the helper's function for the numerical part:

```
# Function to evaluate a curve at a given parameter t
def Z(t, curve):
    point = curve.evaluate_single(t)
    return point[:2]  # Discard the last coordinate (if 3D) 

# Function to calculate the derivative of a curve at a given parameter t
    def Z_derivative(t, curve):
    dpoint = curve.derivatives(t, order=1)
    return np.array(dpoint[1][:2])

# Function to calculate the second derivative of a curve at a given parameter t
def Z_2nd_derivative(t, curve):
    dpoint = curve.derivatives(t, order=2)
    return np.array(dpoint[2][:2])

# Function to determine whether a point is within the NURBS curve
def point_inside_curve(point, curve_points):
    x, y = point
    n = len(curve_points)
    inside = False

    p1x, p1y = curve_points[0]
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        p2x, p2y = curve_points[i % n]
        if y > min(p1y, p2y):
            if y <= max(p1y, p2y):
                if x <= max(p1x, p2x):
                    if p1y != p2y:
                        xinters = (y - p1y) * (p2x - p1x) / (p2y - p1y) + p1x
                    if p1x == p2x or x <= xinters:
                        inside = not inside
        p1x, p1y = p2x, p2y

    return inside
```

and this is the numerical part:

```
N = 100

s_values = np.linspace(0, 1, N+1)
s_values = s_values[:-1]
crvpts = np.array([Z(t, curve) for t in s_values])

xmin = int(min(crvpts[:,0]))
xmax = int(max(crvpts[:,0]))
ymin = int(min(crvpts[:,1]))
ymax = int(max(crvpts[:,1]))
nxgrid = 300
nygrid = 300

x = [Z(s, curve)[0] for s in s_values]
y = [Z(s, curve)[1] for s in s_values]

tx = [Z_derivative(s, curve)[0] for s in s_values]
ty = [Z_derivative(s, curve)[1] for s in s_values]

ax = [Z_2nd_derivative(s, curve)[0] for s in s_values]
ay = [Z_2nd_derivative(s, curve)[1] for s in s_values]

nx = np.zeros(N)
ny = np.zeros(N)
w = np.zeros(N)

for i in range(N):
    nx[i] = ax[i] / np.sqrt(ax[i] ** 2 + ay[i] ** 2)
    ny[i] = ay[i] / np.sqrt(ax[i] ** 2 + ay[i] ** 2)
    h = 1 / (N)
    w[i] = h * np.sqrt(tx[i] ** 2 + ty[i] ** 2)

f = np.zeros(N)
for i in range(N):
    f[i] = (x[i]**2 - y[i]**2) / (2*np.pi)

K = np.zeros((N, N))

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        if i == j:
            kappa = (tx[j] * ax[j] - ty[j] * ay[j]) / (tx[j] ** 2 + ty[j] ** 2) ** 1.5
            kappa = 1
            K[i, j] = -kappa / (4 * np.pi) * w[j]
        else:
            dx = x[j] - x[i]
            dy = y[j] - y[i]
            dot = nx[j] * dx + ny[j] * dy
            r = np.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2)
            K[i, j] = dot / (2 * np.pi * r ** 2)
            K[i, j] = K[i, j] * w[j]

sigma = np.linalg.solve(-np.eye(N) / 2 + K, f)

xlin = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nxgrid)
ylin = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, nygrid)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xlin, ylin)

u = np.zeros((nxgrid, nygrid))
for i in range(nxgrid):
    for j in range(nygrid):
        if not point_inside_curve([X[i,j], Y[i,j]], crvpts):
            u[i, j] = np.nan
        else:
            u[i, j] = 0
        for k in range(N):
            dx = X[i, j] - x[k]
            dy = Y[i, j] - y[k]
            dot = nx[k] * dx + ny[k] * dy
            r = np.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2)
            u[i, j] = u[i, j] - dot / (2 * np.pi * r ** 2) * w[k] * sigma[k]     

plt.imshow(u)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I tried changing the way of computing first and second derivatives, I am sure most of my code is correct (since I have correct solution for the analytic function), the problem should lie somewhere either in where I parametrized the curve or some stupid mistakes within the numerical parts of BIEM implementation.

for reference, below are how I parametrized the code:

```
# Import necessary libraries
import geomdl
import os
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.linalg import solve

from geomdl import BSpline
from geomdl import knotvector
from geomdl import NURBS

import math

cwd = os.getcwd()

# Load control points from CSV file
ctrlpts = []
with open(cwd + '/ctrl_points_file.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row != [] and row != ['x_pos', 'y_pos']:
            ctrlpts.append([float(row[0]), float(row[1])])

# Function to create a NURBS curve from control points
def create_nurbs_curve(control_points):
    # Initialize a NURBS curve object
    curve = NURBS.Curve()

    # Set the degrees of the curve
    curve.degree = 2

    # Set the control points
    curve.ctrlpts = control_points

    # Set the knot vector
    curve.knotvector = knotvector.generate(curve.degree, curve.ctrlpts_size)

    return curve

# Function to evaluate a curve at a given parameter t
def Z(t, curve):
    point = curve.evaluate_single(t)
    return point[:2]  # Discard the last coordinate (if 3D)

curve = create_nurbs_curve(ctrlpts)
```